Columns().Find() in Excel VBA
I am a new user to Excel VBA, I am fairly proficient with matlab, but this one issue I'm running into with excel has got me stumped.
I am searching a sheet for a User ID and then using a different column in that row to change a boolean value. I have a sub that executes this basic procedure, and it works great if a read the data 1 way (using a magnetic strip reader, but is I type the value into a form I created, it will not function.
I have a feeling I am dealing with an issue with types, but I can't pinpoint the problem.
Here is the Sub program,
The UserID is a double and the list is located on the 4th row of the BBgrade worksheet.
Sub CheckWaiver()
    Set gradeSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBgrade") ' Sheet where grades will be stored.
    Set foundBBp = gradeSheet.Columns(4).Find(What:=UserID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    'foundBBp = Application.VLookup(UserID, gradeSheet.ListObjects("tblBBGrades").DataBodyRange, 4, False)
    
    'If Not IsError(foundBBp) Then
    If Not foundBBp Is Nothing Then
        BBrow = foundBBp.Row
        If gradeSheet.Cells(BBrow, 7).Value = 1 Then
            WaiverStatus = True
        Else
            WaiverStatus = False
            MsgBox "We were unable to locate a valid Liability Waiver, please see a student worker"
        End If
    Else
        WaiverStatus = False
        MsgBox "We were unable to find your User ID in our system, please see a student worker."
    End If
End Sub

If I access the sub using this code, everything works fine:
 magData = ws.Range("A1").Value  ' Read first cell of mag data, and split into usable info.
            Dim Arr() As String
            Arr = Split(magData, "^")
            UserName = Arr(1)
            UserID = CDbl(Left(Right(Arr(2), 8), 7))

but when I read the data from an entry, it will not find the user ID in the sheet.
UserName = txtName
UserID = CDbl(txtID)


Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
It may be worth noting that I use the same ws.Columns(4).Find(UserID.... in a different function and that works fine with both methods.

What's txtID? Is a ActiveX control on worksheet or UserForm?

Is the UserId stored on the worksheet as a number? An example of what your inputs look like would be useful here.  If you're not looking for a substring within a cell then LookAt:=xlPart might be better as LookAt:=xlWhole
